# sending request to users in the same model

Tags: forms, yii, controller, request, form-submit

i want to send a request to a user to join community, so firstly i want to check if the  username is exists in the database..then send request data, so how i can do it? here is the code :

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); ?>
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'users-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'userName'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::textField('userName','',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>255, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'userName'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row buttons">
                <?php $urlDe=CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("users/communities/".$model->idUser)); ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Send',array('submit' => $urlDe, 'id'=>'but')); ?>
        <?php //echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' :'Send', array('id'=>'but')); ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::resetButton('Reset', array('id'=>'but')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

this is the invite action..how i can send the invite data to an action belong to the user?
the community and user are in the same model.

Comment: You can do it with a rule, simply use the `unique` rule http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh21

Comment: With that code you create the form twice, you don't need the CHtml::beginForm() and CHtml::endForm().

Comment: You show us some code from a view file. But the question (which is not quite clear) is definitely something for the model.